# Nested Carousel Control not working - click

Tags: javascript, click, carousel, bbc-glow

I have a carousel nested inside another.

The parent carousel is set to loop (infinite). Everything works fine at first until the parent carousel loops, then the nested carousel loses it click function on the controls and stops working.

demo: http://lroomukp.com/carsel/nested.html

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks guys